# Recover encfs folder password

Tags: linux-mint, encfs

Is it possible that a chown or any other rights access (delete, write, read, etc) makes the encryption bugs?

Yesterday, I have encrypted a folder with encfs on Linux Mint.
Today i tried to open it with the password and it tolds me that the password wasn't correct...
I told myself that i maybe wrote the password in a bad way! So i tested with capital letters, i tested with characters and numbers around the ones i used in my password, with no positive results...

So, could it be a bug coming from somewhere or the was me having typed my password incorrectly (crazy, because, you have to type it two times...).
If it is the second, do somebody knows how to crack the password or take it back? I can give my .encfs6.xml file to this person and give my password, in order for the person to see that i am in the good owner of this file!

I was in a hurry, moving personal files to this folder on another hdd... hmmmmm, how could this be? this almost extraordinary! I am for a quadruple check password for this kind of manipulation or for everypasswords...

I thank you very much.

Comment: "_do somebody knows how to crack the password_" The point of having string encryption (or any encryption at all, really) is that it shouldn't be possible to "crack" the password except by brute-force guessing.

Answer (score 0):

> In order to decrypt a file, two things are required (besides the
>   encrypted file data): the password, and the “.encfs5” control file at
>   the top level of the raw encfs filesystem... The control file contains
>   the filesystem parameters, in addition to encrypted key data which is
>   different for every filesystem.. **You need both the password and this
>   control file in order to access the data. If you loose either one,
>   there isn’t anything I can do to help.** - https://sites.google.com/a/arg0.net/www/encfsintro

In short, like with any encryption system worthy of the name: no password/key, no data.